# how to put items in an array sequentially?(javascript)

Tags: javascript

I wonder the title is right or not,

anyway what I wonder is how can do thing like this

```
const items = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9 .. and so on ]

const flexbox1 = [];
const flexbox2 = [];
const flexbox3 = [];
const flexbox4 = [];



for (const item in items) {

// what I wonder is this part. 

      }


==> result:

const flexbox1 = [a1,a5,a9,a13 .. and so on];
const flexbox2 = [a2,a6,a10,a14 .. and so on];
const flexbox3 = [a3,a7,a11,a15 .. and so on];
const flexbox4 = [a4,a8,a12,a16 ... and so on];
```

How can I get the results above??

I've been trying for two days to find the answer in the book and on the internet, but I couldn't find it.

please help ....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
const items = [...Array(20).keys()];

const flexbox1 = [];
const flexbox2 = [];
const flexbox3 = [];
const flexbox4 = [];

const boxes = [flexbox1, flexbox2, flexbox3, flexbox4];

items.forEach((item, index) => {
    boxes[index % 4].push(item);
});

console.log(flexbox1);
console.log(flexbox2);
console.log(flexbox3);
console.log(flexbox4);
```

Answer (score 6):

Below is one approach to put items into the 4 buckets using the modulo operator. This solution can be extended to account for any number of buckets. The function `allocateFlexboxes` in the snippet achieves just that.

Once the `for` loop ends, you can access desired flexbox by the index.

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]


let flexBoxes = [[], [], [], []];

for (let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
  const bucketIndex = i % 4;

  flexBoxes[bucketIndex].push(items[i]);
}

console.log("Bucket size: 4");
console.log(flexBoxes);

// Generic function that can accommodate for any number
const allocateFlexboxes = (items, flexBoxCount) => {
  let flexBoxes = [...new Array(flexBoxCount)].map(x => [])
  
  items.forEach((item, index) => {
    const bucketIndex = index % flexBoxCount;
    
    flexBoxes[bucketIndex].push(item);
  });
  
  return flexBoxes;
}
```

Comment: I was too slow in writing my solution, so no need to post a further answer. +1 to this one because it is clean (and it has at least a minimal explanation)

Answer (score 6):

use a simple `for` loop incrementing the counter by 4 :

```js
const items = Array.from({ length: 40 }, (_, i) => "a" + (i+1));

const flexbox1 = [];
const flexbox2 = [];
const flexbox3 = [];
const flexbox4 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i += 4) {
  flexbox1.push(items[i]);
  flexbox2.push(items[i + 1]);
  flexbox3.push(items[i + 2]);
  flexbox4.push(items[i + 3]);
}

console.log({
  flexbox1,
  flexbox2,
  flexbox3,
  flexbox4
});
```

Comment: Of all answers this is most efficient in terms of performance.

Comment: this might push `undefined` onto flexbox2, flexbox3 and flexbox4 in case of array length being not divisible by 4

Comment: you might consider changing the condition of the for loop to `i<items.length -3` and manually pushing the last few elements outside of the loop if they exist

Answer (score 4):

I think it is not the cleanest solution, but it should work :)

```js
const items = [...Array(20).keys()];

let currentIndex = 1;
const data = {
  flexbox1: [],
  flexbox2: [],
  flexbox3: [],
  flexbox4: []
};

for (const item in items) {
  data[`flexbox${currentIndex}`].push(item);
  currentIndex = currentIndex === 4 ? 1 : currentIndex + 1;
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
const items = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10','a11','a12']

const flexbox1 = [];
const flexbox2 = [];
const flexbox3 = [];
const flexbox4 = [];



items.forEach((item,index)=> {
  if( index%4 ==0 ) { flexbox1.push(item) }
  else if( index%4 ==1 ) { flexbox2.push(item) }
  else if( index%4 ==2 ) { flexbox3.push(item) }
  else if( index%4 ==3 ) { flexbox4.push(item) }
})


console.log(flexbox1);
console.log(flexbox2);
console.log(flexbox3);
console.log(flexbox4);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
let r1 = [], r2 = [], r3 = [], r4 = [];
let x = 0;
const items = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9"];
for (let i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
if (x % 4 === 0) {
    r1.push(items[i]);
    x++;
} else if (x % 4 === 1) {
    r2.push(items[i]);
    x++;
} else if (x % 4 === 2) {
    r3.push(items[i]);
    x++;
} else if (x % 4 === 3) {
    r4.push(items[i]);
    x++;
}
}
console.log(r1, r2, r3, r4);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to allocate items in 4 different arrays, you can push each item to a different array according to their index modulo 4.

```js
const items = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10']

const flexbox1 = [];
const flexbox2 = [];
const flexbox3 = [];
const flexbox4 = [];

const flexboxes = [flexbox1, flexbox2, flexbox3, flexbox4];

items.map((item, index) => {
  flexboxes[index%4].push(item);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this once upon a time.  Here's the function I wound up writing.  It takes a slightly different approach than pushing items into an array.  I have no idea if it's faster, but **all the array sizes are known up front** with this approach.  It also handles having leftover columns and having too few items to fill all rows.

```js
let to2D = (items, n) => [...Array(Math.min(items.length, n))].map(
  (_, row) => [...Array((items.length + n - 1 - row) / n >>> 0)].map(
    (_, column) => items[column * n + row]
  )
);


let exampleItems = [...Array(17).keys()].map(i => `a${i + 1}`);
console.log(to2D(exampleItems, 4))
```

FYI Output:

```
[
  [ 'a1', 'a5', 'a9', 'a13', 'a17' ],
  [ 'a2', 'a6', 'a10', 'a14' ],
  [ 'a3', 'a7', 'a11', 'a15' ],
  [ 'a4', 'a8', 'a12', 'a16' ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  flexbox1.push(items[4 * i]);
  flexbox2.push(items[4 * i + 1]);
  flexbox3.push(items[4 * i + 2]);
  flexbox4.push(items[4 * i + 3]);

}
```

```js
const items = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9"]

const flexbox1 = [];
const flexbox2 = [];
const flexbox3 = [];
const flexbox4 = [];


for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  flexbox1.push(items[4 * i]);
  flexbox2.push(items[4 * i + 1]);
  flexbox3.push(items[4 * i + 2]);
  flexbox4.push(items[4 * i + 3]);

}

document.querySelector('.foo').innerHTML = flexbox1 + "<br>" + flexbox2 + "<br>" + flexbox3 + "<br>" + flexbox4;
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
```

This method isn't perfect as it keeps adding elements in the array until the `items.length` is reached, but should be enough to get the idea.

Comment: There was no need to add extra jsFiddle demo, as you already added a working code snippet demo here. Just wanted to let you know.